# You have already activated rack 1.6.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.6.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rack, gemfile

Similar to [problem with rack 1.3.2. You have already activated rack 1.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323357/problem-with-rack-1-3-2-you-have-already-activated-rack-1-3-2-but-your-gemfile) -- I'm experiencing `You have already activated rack 1.6.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.6.4` when attempting to run Rails (4.2) in production with Puma and Nginx.

`bundle update rake` nor `rm Gemfile.lock && bundle install` seem to help, the only solution I have so far is manually changing `rack (1.6.4)` to `rack (1.6.0)` in Gemfile.lock.

Comment: this is similar to your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241912/how-to-force-rack-to-work-around-the-usual-you-have-already-activated-rack. you have to remove rack version 1.6.0 like this  `gem uninstall rack -v 1.6.0`

Comment: Have you tried binstub? Check the answer below

Comment: That did indeed to the trick @Athar - tyvm!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to uninstall one version of rack which is not required.

Do this please

```
gem uninstall rack -v 1.6.0
```

Reference: [How to force rack to work around the usual "You have already activated rack..." bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241912/how-to-force-rack-to-work-around-the-usual-you-have-already-activated-rack)

Answer (score 2):

One experienced Rails developer [highly recommends](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/01/understanding-binstubs/) using binstubs. Have it installed by:

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

and run it via relative path:

```
./bin/rails server
```

or what is most recommended update PATH and forget about bundler issues:

```
export PATH="./bin:$PATH"
rails server
```

Comment: Nope, this is in production using Puma. Athar's comment above fixed it though. Thanks!

Comment: It will happen again if not fixed properly

Answer (score 1):

Run it like this: `bundle exec rails s`. This will use settings from your Gemfile.lock

Comment: Thanks, but see Athar's comment above.

Comment: No matter how carefully you install or uninstall gems you will end up with multiple versions. Running it is bundle exec is the right way to do it and removes version ambiguity from your deployment

Comment: @Zepplock right, "binstubs" is a way to avoid prepend *bundle exec* all the time

Answer (score 1):

These issues might arise if you are using local or global gemset for more than one project. Why not create seprate gemset for each project.

You can do this using rvm

Create new gemset

```
rvm gemset create new_test

rvm gemset use new_test

bundle install
```

Comment: Indeed. Multiple projects was my issue and this is a clean solution. Also, adding #ruby-gemset=new_test to the Gemfile sets the gemset for the project

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run below cmd to get the latest rack installed in server to fix the issue:

```
gem install rack
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue:

**Here's my solution**:

**Solution 1**:

This solution works a lot of the time, simply update the gem causing the issue.

```
bundle update rack
```

**Solution 2**:

In some cases **Solution 1** may not work, and you will need to edit your `Gemfile.lock` file.

Simply, open your `Gemfile.lock` file and then change the version to the update requested.

In my case, I had `rack 2.0.7` defined in my `Gemfile.lock` file, but my application required `rack 2.1.2`, I simply had to modify it to `rack 2.1.2` in the `Gemfile.lock` file.

I then had to uninstall the previous version of rack which is `rack 2.0.7`

```
 gem uninstall rack -v 2.0.7
```

And finally installed the new gem in production

```
bundle install --without development test
```

**Solution 3**:

In very rare cases **Solution 1** and **Solution 2** may not work, and you will need to edit your `Gemfile` before updating the gem.

In my case, the gem was `puma`, I had `puma ~> 3.11` defined in my `Gemfile`, but my application required `puma ~> 4.3.1`. At this point running `bundle update puma` and editing my `Gemfile.lock` file didn't work, since `puma ~> 3.11` version specified in the Gemfile would not allow an update to `puma ~> 4.3.1`.

I simply had to change the version of puma in the Gemfile to `puma ~> 4.3.1` and then ran the command.

```
bundle update puma
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**