# You have already activated rack 2.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rack 2.0.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried all available solutions but didn't get the result. I even uninstalled the rack and then run the bundle install but getting same issue.

tried command:

```
 -gem uninstall rack
 -gem pristine --all
```

but everytime it shows that You have already activated rack 2.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rack 2.0.6 in log errors.

Comment: may be you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/31812867/938947

Comment: already done, problme still exists

Comment: Try bundle update, to update all gems

Comment: done but same error

Comment: I have solution

Comment: can you please share the solution

Comment: I will post just wait 2mins

Comment: @MohammadShahbaz i posted answer ask me if you are struggle in between..Thanks Advance!